# Big-o analysis of performing an O(n) within a loop executing n! times

Tags: algorithm, loops, big-o, time-complexity

I'm trying to determine the time complexity of the following:

```
while loop that executes n! times {

     perform an operation that is O(n)

  }
```

Would the big-o analysis still be `O(n!)`?  I don't see how it would be `O(n^n)`.  Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: and yes I know this is terribly inefficient

Comment: Why do you think `O(n^n)` is a possibility?

Comment: It's worse than `O(n^n)`

Comment: The efficiency would just be n*n!, your doing n work n! times

Comment: I don't really, but I feel like this can't be O(n!) since, I believe, the worst case might actually take longer.  As far as I know, O(n^n) is the next time complexity set up, so I figure maybe it would fall into that threshold.

Comment: @megawac : And you got that how?

Comment: @Philip: You're doing n * n! work, which is approximately (n+1)!.  Ok, it's exactly (n+1)! - n!.

Comment: @megawac: Why would it be worse than O(n^n) and if so, what set would be slower?

Comment: @JoeZ you do `n!` work `n` times. `n!` > `x^n` - In his case the runtime is `O(n*n!)`

Comment: @megawac: Wouldn't we actually be comparing n! to n^n?  In which case n^n > n!

Comment: @megawac:  n * n! < (n+1)!.  However, n^n > n!.

Comment: @Philip: `In which case n^n > n!` - for every case this is true, coz `n^n = n*n*n*n...n times` and `n! = n*(n-1)*(n-2)*...*1`, so you can see clearly `n!` is always less for any value of `n`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just think about it algebraically, how would multiplying n*n! ever give you n^n, it wont.. n! iterations doing n work is just n*n!

Comment: Ok this makes sense, but as far as I'm aware there isn't an O(n*n!) set.  Is it still actually O(n!)?

Comment: let me ask you this question...if you were looping n times and doing log(n) work every time would the complexity be O(n)...no..its nlog(n)....just as here it would be O(n*n!)

Comment: Right, it would be O(n log n), which is a specified set I've seen on time complexity graphs before.  I'm just confused because n*n! will grow significantly faster than n! so I don't understand why it would be O(n!).  I get it if it is in fact O(n*n!), I just didn't realize you could specify other sets like this.

Comment: I see where you are coming from, however, n is a significant amount of extra work to just ignore for a large data set

Comment: So to be clear, I can specify that the algorithm above would run in O(n*n!) time?  I have yet to take an algorithms class, so my confusion comes from only ever seeing the standard: O(1), O(log n), O(n), O(n log n), O(n^2), O(2^n), O(n!), and O(n^n).

Comment: Ya, I wouldnt get too hung up on a chart of common big O...i mean if you have thousands of data, and you are doing n work n! times, thats alot more than 1 work every n! times

Comment: Great, I never realized we could specify more specific sets of big-o!  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you really want an equivalent, then your solution is :

```
O(n^(n+3/2) / e^n)
```

This comes from [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) which states `n! = O(n^(n+1/2)/e^n)`

Answer (score 0):

You are doing n work for n! times. It's just O(n*n!).

Answer (score 0):

It's not `O(n^n)`. It's complexity is `O(n*n!)`

You can very easily trace this by calculating for the different values of `n`:

> when n = 1, inner operation executes 1 time
>   when n = 2, inner operation executes 2 times
>   when n = 3, inner operation executes 6 times
>   when n = 4, inner operation executes 24 times

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to understand what big-O notation means:

`f(x) = O(g(x))` if there exist integers `N` and `c`, such that for `n >= N`, `f(x) <= c g(x)`.

You cannot say your code is `O(n!)` because `n*n!` will, for large enough `n`, always be greater than `c n!` for any `c`.

**Proof:** Suppose there existed integers `c, N` such that for `n >= N, d*n*n! < c*n! => d*n < c for n >= N` which is a contradiction.